# Laravel override mail to automatically add plain text version

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm making some changes in my Laravel app to automatically add plain text version to my e-mails.. I'm doing that by using the library

https://packagist.org/packages/html2text/html2text

I would get the text version by running

```
\Html2Text\Html2Text::convert($content)
```

Now I want to override laravels Mailable.php buildView() function to automaticaly generate the text. My question is: how to properly override it? Where can I redeclare it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mailer is defined by the Mailer Service Provider, you can see the registration of it in your `config/app.php` under `'providers'`, where you will see this:

```
\Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
```

So, all you need to do, is remove the MailServiceProvider registration and create your own Provider based on that one with your changes and register yours.

Make sure you implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer` contract.

**But you don't need to!**

The mailer that comes with Laravel already support sending the HTML and Plain versions of your email.

The `Mailer::send()` method's first argument is `@param  string|array  $view`, where you usually send the view name of the HTML version of your email, but, you can instead send an array like this...

```
Mailer::send([
    'html' => 'my-mails.notification-in-html',
    'text' => 'my-mails.notification-in-text',
  ], $data, $callback);
```

Where you could even define a different text and remove things that you would not put in your plain text version, or adjust a different signature that looks good on plain, and also format things different.

For more information you can look at the `parseView()` in `Illuminate\Mail\Mailer` class.

So, there you have it, 2 options:

- Create your own Mailer and register it instead of the default one
- or just call the mailer with an array of views.

Answer (score 2):

When I was needed to use the same HTML template for plain text version, I've overriden the Mailable in the following way:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

// [...] some other imports

use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;

class BaseMailable extends Mailable
{
    // [...] some other code

    /**
     * Method to add plain text version by converting it from HTML version
     * Separate plain text view could be used if exists
     */
    public function viewHtmlWithPlainText($view, array $data = [])
    {
        // NOTE: we render HTML separately because HTML and Plain versions have the same data
        // and we need to pass `plain` parameter to the HTML template to render it differently
        $this->html( view($view, $this->buildViewData())->render() );

        $plainTextView = str_replace('emails.', 'emails.txt.', $view);
        $plainTextAttrs = [
            'plain' => true,
            'senderName' => config('app.name')
        ];
        if (view()->exists($plainTextView)) {
            $this->text( $plainTextView, array_merge($plainTextAttrs, $data) );
        } else {
            $this->text( $view, array_merge($plainTextAttrs, $data) );
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And then in child Mailable you can use it like `view()` method before:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Mail\BaseMailable;

class UserResetPasswordLink extends BaseMailable
{
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->subject(trans('ui.reset_password'))
            ->viewHtmlWithPlainText('emails.client.user-reset-password-link', [
                'token' => $this->token,
            ]);
    }
}
```

And in templates you'll have `$plain=true` variable for Plain Text emails so you can re-use HTML template files for plain text with

```
@if (empty($plain))
<div>Some HTML content</div>
@else
Some plain text content
@endif
```