# How to send both html and text-only version of an email stored in a single Laravel blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I thought this would be a lot more straightforward, but if I want to send an email stored in an email blade template from a Laravel Mailable class, I have to do something like this in the build method:

```
        return $this->from(config('mail.from_domain.address'), config('mail.from_domain.name'))
    ->replyTo(config('mail.from_domain.address'), config('mail.from_domain.name'))
    ->subject('Please confirm your email')
    ->view('mail.domain.email_confirmation_html')
    ->with([
        'emailConfirmationLink' => $this->emailConfirmationLink,
    ])
    ->text('mail.domain.email_confirmation_text')
    ->with([
        'emailConfirmationLink' => $this->emailConfirmationLink,
    ]);
```

Unfortunately, this means that for every email I will ever send, I will have to keep/maintain two versions of what's basically the exact same email content (the html and text-only version).

So my question is, could I possibly store only the html version (not markdown) and generate/convert the text-only version on the fly (so without having to store it into a separate blade file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel override mail to automatically add plain text version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429422/laravel-override-mail-to-automatically-add-plain-text-version)

Comment: This answer looks promising but I haven't tried it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56541880/1255289